# Como puedo obtener los datos de un entry || Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero que al pulsar un botón se actualizen los datos del `StringVar()` para luego obtenerlos y poder ponerlos en una *ListBox*, pero tengo el problema que no se como hacer para que se actualize el `StringVar()` y que lo agregue a la *ListBox*, en mi codigo lo agrega a la *ListBox* pero en blanco y no con los datos del *Entry*

Mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


ventana = tk.Tk()
global nombre
nombre = StringVar()

def agregarAlumno():
    nombreLista.insert(0,nombre.get())

    print("")


def agregarAlumno():
    ventanaAgregar = Tk()
    ventanaAgregar.title("Agregar alumno")

    Label(ventanaAgregar,text="Nombre:").place(x=0,y=0)
    Entry(ventanaAgregar,textvariable=nombre).place(x=55,y=0)

    botonAgregar = Button(ventanaAgregar,text="Agregar", command=obtenerAlumno)
    botonAgregar.place(x=50,y=100)


menu = Menu(ventana)

menuLista = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="Lista",menu=menuLista)
menuLista.add_command(label="Agregar alumno",command=agregarAlumno)
menuLista.add_command(label="Salir")

nombreLista = Listbox(ventana,width=27)
nombreLista.place(x=1,y=30)


ventana.config(menu=menu)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cambiado `global nombre` por pasarle el contenido del `Entry` por parametro al metodo `agregarAlumno()` de esta forma:

```
botonAgregar = tk.Button(ventanaAgregar, text="Agregar",
                         command=lambda: agregarAlumno(nombre.get()))
```

El codigo quedaria asi:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()

def agregarAlumno(nombre):
    nombreLista.insert(0, nombre)


def obtenerAlumno():
    ventanaAgregar = tk.Tk()
    ventanaAgregar.title("Agregar alumno")

    tk.Label(ventanaAgregar, text="Nombre:").place(x=0, y=0)
    nombre = tk.Entry(ventanaAgregar)
    nombre.place(x=55, y=0)

    botonAgregar = tk.Button(ventanaAgregar, text="Agregar",
                         command=lambda: agregarAlumno(nombre.get()))
    botonAgregar.place(x=50, y=100)


menu = tk.Menu(ventana)

menuLista = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

nombreLista = tk.Listbox(ventana, width=27)
nombreLista.place(x=1, y=30)

menu.add_cascade(label="Lista", menu=menuLista)
menuLista.add_command(label="Agregar alumno", command=obtenerAlumno)
menuLista.add_command(label="Salir")

ventana.config(menu=menu)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!